# Get Date by supplying a month and year

Tags: swift, date, calendar, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I’m trying to create a Date extension static function that accepts two parameters: `(month: Int, year: Int)` and returns `-> Date`.

The month that is returned would be its .startOfMonth:

```
var startOfMonth: Date {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: self)
    return  calendar.date(from: components)!
}
```

I know how to retrieve a month in the future by adding n-months to the current:

```
func addMonths(_ numMonths: Int) -> Date {
    let cal = NSCalendar.current
    return cal.date(byAdding: .month, value: numMonths, to: self)!
}
```

And I suppose this could be used in a roundabout way to determine what I’m looking for, by first determining how many months from the current is the month I’m interested in getting a Date returned for. But I would much prefer if I could retrieve it without needing to go through this step, especially if there’s a possibility that I’m not actually sure if the month is in fact in the future.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson his extension would return the start of month for an instance of a date. What OP wants is to specify the year and month.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I did understand the question. Not sure what it is not clear for you.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I agree with your last comment but the first one didn't make sense.

Comment: Apologies if the question came across as more of a request. To be clear, I had no knowledge whatsoever on how to implement this (despite many searches before posting) which is why the question didn’t include any failed attempts that would lead to a clear question/problem.

Comment: FWIW, I’ve edited the question for the benefit of any future viewers of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateComponents initializer to compose a new date just passing the month and year components. Just make sure to pass a calendar as well otherwise the result would be nil. Maybe something like:

```
extension Date {
    static func startOfMonth(for month: Int, of year: Int, using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date? {
        DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: year, month: month).date
    }
}

Date.startOfMonth(for: 2, of: 2021)  // "Feb 1, 2021 at 12:00 AM"
```

Comment: Thanks so much Leo. I had a feeling this capability would be relatively straightforward to accomplish, but perhaps it was so basic that it wasn’t something I had seen anything written about. And, agreed, about it being a static function (I did realise this originally).